Error when installing the DPP library: this platform is not supported by FindSodium.cmake
I trying to set up the DPP library to work with a discord bot for fun in my project. I have followed the installation instructions, but I am facing issues during the build process.
My Setup (I don't want to switch to Linux)

OS: Windows 11
MSYS2 installed in C:\msys64
I installed libsodium and configured the environment variables.

CMake Command I'm running
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"

And I always get this annoying error:
"ChineseWorker@DESKTOP-IOBRH22 MINGW64 /mingw64/include/dpp/build
$ cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
-- INFO: Using VCPKG if detected
-- INFO: Configuring .rc resource script
-- Detected AMD64 AVX type: AVX0 (FLAGS: )
CMake Error at cmake/FindSodium.cmake:196 (message):
  this platform is not supported by FindSodium.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  library/CMakeLists.txt:118 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
"


Too little info. How did you install libsodium? How are you searching for it?

Please add the output of which cmake and which g++.

mingw is not supported in this library.
it comes with the dependencies it needs, use wsl, clang-cl or msvc 2022.
for msvc 2022 there is a template project which is ready to go, you do not need to install dependencies: https://github.com/brainboxdotcc/windows-bot-template
For wsl and clang-cl there is a cmake based template project:
https://github.com/brainboxdotcc/templatebot

also, from 10.0.32 onwards sodium is not required for voice; only opus. one less dependency to worry about!

What makes you think they don't support mingw? Just tried building it with it, didn't have any issues.

the fact that i created the library makes me think it doesnt support mingw @HolyBlackCat

Are you saying you didn't test on mingw? Or that you found some problem with mingw that prevents your library from working on it? Because the compilation seems to work on my side.

im saying its explicitly not supported, if you get it to work, you got further than we did, but we don't support it as it has issues with threading, and with its sockets implementation. It is just a bad unofficial fork of gcc. Also, just tried to get it to build on msys2 as i was curious from what you said. I can't. I get "too many sections" and "file too big". It has some weird restriction that proper g++ does not.

I'm curious, what are those issues with threading and sockets you're talking about?

It worked for me when I cross-compiled from Linux using Clang in MinGW mode. :) Tried it on a Windows VM using GCC, got some weird undefined references, and stopped at that for now. MinGW isn't a fork of GCC by the way, it's a collection of tools and libraries (that can be used by compilers other than GCC, e.g. Clang). The LD linker isn't a part of MinGW.
